# How to Mock methods return types, If it called asynchronously using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

I created a thread pool of 100 threads and called three asynchronous calls. How can I mock asynchronous calls which return objects like the following when writing unit tests:

1. `LocationDetail(finalUserInformation, placeInformation)`
2. `pgData(finalUserInformation, pgInformation)`
3. `userContactData(finalUserInformation, userContactList)`

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();

UserInformation finalUserInformation = userInformation;
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return LocationDetail(finalUserInformation,placeInformation);
    }});

callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return  pgData(finalUserInformation,pgInformation);

    }});

callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return usercontactData(finalUserInformation,userContactList);
    }});

try {
    List<Future<String>> futures = service.invokeAll(callables);
    for (Future<String> future : futures) {
        System.out.println(future.get());
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

}
```

Comment: Ideally your three method calls should belong to a dependency which you then just mock as usual. As your method is blocking and the order of the invocation does not seem to matter there is no real difference between a normal unit test. If you can't refactor the code using a spy would be an option.

Comment: when(service1.LocationDetail(anyString())).thenReturn(information1);
 when(service2.pgData(anyString())).thenReturn(information2);                         when(service3.usercontactData(anyString())).thenReturn(information3);    
     I mock synchronically but It’s not mocked. I get "null" value

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete and runnable unit test. Also update you code with the surrounding method, the related class and its constructors. If you do that we can check where the error is coming from.

Comment: If you could provide either all the previous things asked or even better a small project containing the bare minimal to reproduce the error. ! Many people find the solution while building those example projects